# Storing my file of strings into my vector thinks I am trying to put characters in it?

Tags: c++, fstream

When trying to use fstream to enter csv data into my program I am having an odd problem using a vector but it works fine with a random-sized array. I am not sure why but the error I am getting from visual studio is that there is no suitable conversion from string to char even though my vector is for strings. I am not sure if this is happening because of some weird case where it is trying to push back something I didn't intend even though I double-checked it by putting outputs to see where it was happening.

```
==== Function ====
ifstream dataEve;
dataEve.open(fileName, std::ifstream::in);

std::vector<std::vector<string>> dataStore;
//string dataStore[10][10];                  ***works if you replace the vector above***

string currentLine;
string currentObject;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

while (!dataEve.eof()) {
    getline(dataEve, currentLine, '\n');
    stringstream ss(currentLine);
    string currentLine;
    while (std::getline(ss, currentObject, ',')) {
        dataStore[x][y].push_back(currentObject);
        //dataStore[x][y] = currentObject;        ***works fine if you use this too***
        std::cout << currentObject << "\t";
        y++;
    }
    x++;
    std::cout << "\n";
}
std::cout << "\n\n";

dataEve.close();

==== fileName.csv ====
Organism,Genetic Code
Felis catus,ACTG
Canis lupis,ATCG
```

Comment: Accessing any element of a 0 x 0 vector of vectors is always UB. Try `dataStore.at(x).at(y)` and the program throws the first time you're accessing an invalid combination indices...

Comment: It's good to learn a bit about C++ before going _all-in_. It's a very unforgiving language. If you think _"yeah, it'll probably work like it does in the other language I know "_- no, it doesn't.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `ifstream dataEve; dataEve.open(fileName, std::ifstream::in);` to `ifstream dataEve(fileName, std::ifstream::in);` or, even better, `ifstream dataEve(fileName);`. Also, you don’t need to call `dataEve.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
dataStore.push_back(std::vector<string>()); // add a new 'row'
while (std::getline(ss, currentObject, ',')) {
    dataStore.back().push_back(currentObject); // push the string onto the last 'row'
    std::cout << currentObject << "\t";
    y++;
}
x++;
```

As you can see from this code you don't actually need the `x` and `y` variables, but I left them in anyway.

Two errors in your code, firstly `dataStore[x][y]` doesn't exist as the vector has zero size, so that would be a run time error.

Secondly `dataStore[x][y]` is a string, so if you `push_back` on a string the compiler expects you to give a `char`. That's the reason for the compiler error.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation with that, it was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are syntax error:

1. dataStore - vector of vector of string
2. dataStore [x] - x's vector of string in the vector dataStore
3. dataStore [x][y] - y's string in the x's vector in the vector dataStore
4. dataStore [x][y].push_back(...) - pushback is the method of class string which push only the one character (char) to the end
5. currentObject - is object which type is string, not char => error